# attempt to index number with 'Value' can someone help fix this?

Tags: roblox

this is a local script to display the text of "*/*" the script is in a screen gui along with the values and textlabels.

```
local total = script.Total
local collect = script.Collect
local Backpack = script.Parent
local text = Backpack.Frame.Backpack


total = 10
text.Text = collect.Value.."/"..total.Value --Error line--
```

I was hoping this would place the collected value /(out of) the total value but I'm getting this error instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that a number doesn't have properties, yet you are trying to find one.

This is because you overwrote the original value of `total` with this line : `total = 10`. At this point, `total` is no longer a NumberValue it is now simply a number.

If you want to set the Value of the NumberValue to 10, you need to set the property.

```lua
total.Value = 10
```